# Delphi project error in using dylib on OSX

Tags: macos, delphi

I use Delphi 10.1 Berlin. I've created anapplication, which I launch using this library(library on C)

First time I launched it I had an error that libhid.dylib was not found. I've added it to rpath and the error was resolved.

But now when I've opened the application and when I'm trying to call a method from the library I get next:

```
Process:               Project2 [8538]
Path:                  /Users/USER/*/Project2.app/Contents/MacOS/Project2  
Identifier:            Project2 
Version:               1.0.0 (1.0.0)
Code Type:             X86 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Project2 [8538]
User ID:               506

Date/Time:             2018-01-23 14:03:14.976 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.12.6 (16G29)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        4E81F6AB-1EEF-F9C1-160C-A01D8944D786

Sleep/Wake UUID:       DB3C055B-BE55-40B8-88A5-6D5530E284AB . 

Time Awake Since Boot: 140000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       14000 seconds



System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    DYLD, [0x4] Symbol missing

Dyld Error Message:
Symbol not found: _DeleteAll
Referenced from: /Users/USER/*/Project2.app/Contents/MacOS/Project2
Expected in: /usr/local/lib/libhidlib.dylib
```

Here is my code where I link library:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes,     System.Variants,
FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls;

type
TForm1 = class(TForm)
Button1: TButton;
procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
private
{ Private declarations }
public
{ Public declarations }
end;


{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
function DeleteAll():shortstring; stdcall; external 'Project1.dll' delayed;
{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF MACOS}
function _DeleteAll():shortstring; cdecl; external 'libhidlib.dylib'  ;
{$ENDIF}

 var
 Form1: TForm1;

 implementation
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

So, after few weeks searching for info i found, that after release new OS X version programmers changed file structure for OS X(10.9 100%)

What about delphi. Projects may connect to library but can't use it's methods.